# Python and SQLite Query Strings - Python String Formatting

Tags: python, sql, string-formatting

I've been reading up on string formatting, concatenation, etc in Python and ran into an issue. Given a python object, how come this works in SQLite:

```
for table in tables:
    query = 'PRAGMA table_info(%s);' % table
    results = connection.execute(query)
    . . .
```

but this doesn't:

```
for table in tables:
    query = 'PRAGMA table_info({0});'.format(table)
    results = connection.execute(query)
```

Error for the second version:

```
database error: near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: What does `print repr(query)` give you?

Comment: `print repr(query)` shows something like this: `u'PRAGMA table_info(<table_name>);'` where `<table_name>` is something like `Cars`.